# Huion Tablet WH1409 and Ubuntu 20.04: is there a way of making it work using the cable?

Tags: drivers, usb, tablet, graphics-tablet

I'm not new to Ubuntu, but I am not an expert.

My tablet, HUION WH1409, is recognised by my system only when I use the wireless connection. If I use the usb cable it doesn't seem to work.

I've installed the Digimed drivers. The only issue I have is that the battery life of my tablet is really short and I can't work for more than 5 minutes before it stops working.

I would like to use the usb cable instead of the wireless connection. Is there any way to do it?

Thank you for your attention.

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1210:000a DigiTech Lexicon Alpha
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 256c:006e PenTablet 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Is this a new  tablet? 5 minutes is a super short time for a battery to last. They have their own support site. https://www.huion.com/support.html

Comment: As a workaround, can you connect to the tablet via wireless, and simultaneously use the USB cable for charging?

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't. As soon as I connect the USB cable the tablet stops to be recognised. 

The tablet is not new. I have been using it on Windows for three years at least, but I've always used it using the USB cable.

Comment: Connect it to the computer with USB, and post the output of the command `lsusb`. Please edit the question with the output. https://askubuntu.com/posts/1362156/edit